# Is there a way to check with ansible if a patch has been applied?

Tags: patch, ansible

I was wondering if there's a way to determine using an ansible playbook whether a patch has been applied or not. For example i have a shell script I need to patch and afterwards use it's patched version. If it has been patched just skip the task.

At this moment my playbook fails when I try to do the patching task, because it has been done at a previous attempt, and errors when trying to patch the patched file.
Thanks

Comment: Do you use the patch module? The easiest should be to simply ignore errors on that task or define a more sophisticated condition with `failed_when`.

Comment: Ok, using ignore_errors would be the quickest, easiest... and partially ok-ish solution. I guess that if I want a complex evaluation of the task, i shouldnt ignore the errors concerning the integrity of the patch, which can occur when trying to apply it - errors which need to generate a failure for the entire playbook.

Comment: You should be able to only catch the state where the patch has already been applied. Something like `failed_when: "some string" not in foo.sdterr or foo.failed = false` where "some string" would be in the stderr when the patch has already been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the md5 of the file and apply the patch only if the checksum is not the one you expect:

```
- stat: path=/my/file get_md5=yes
  register: file_md5
- patch: ...
  when: file_md5.stat.md5 != myexpectedmd5
```

Comment: instead of `get_md5`, use `get_checksum` which generates sha1.

Comment: It's worth saying this *only* works if the file is *exactly* the same as another file you know about. If you have even one character difference it won't match the sha1/md5 and you'll get a fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could also test before patching.

```
patch -R --dry-run -f  < patchfile;
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then
  patch -f < patchfile
fi
```

Which as a one-liner (and using [||](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03) rather than if..then) would be:

```
patch -R --dry-run -f < patchfile || patch -R -f < patchfile
```

Basically it attempts to do a dry-run of patch -R which attempts to revert the patch, then if that would fail it attempts to patch it.

This isn't without its shortcomings however, as both commands can fail.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this that combines the two answers already given here is to create a new, empty file with your [patch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/patch_module.html), and then filtering against (with [stat](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/stat_module.html)) whether that file exists or not before applying the patch.

```
diff -urN mycode-0.1/is-patched mycode-0.1/is-patched
--- mycode-0.1/is-patched      1970-01-01 10:00:00.000000000 +1000
+++ mycode-0.1/is-patched      2018-04-18 10:00:00.000000000 +1000
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+
```

Then as part of your task

```
- stat: path=/my/directory/is-patched
  register: mypatch
- patch: ...
  when: mypatch.stat.exists == false
```

This avoids needing a hash of one of the updated files.